# Is it possible to make FB Application albums private by default?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am uploading some photos by Graph API and I want to make my application album private by default so that it won't spam the news feed of other users. Or maybe there is an option for it to not post every upload on news feed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have privacy parameter. I haven't tested it with photos yet but it works fine with albums and posts. Pass the privacy object along with access_token or other fields.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

See the privacy field in above link.

Answer (score 0):

To upload photos without the corresponding news feed story, there's a no_story parameter you can include when uploading the photo

This is documented in the ['photos' part of the 'User' Graph API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos)